# Why do I get an extra output in my code?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I'm trying to write a code which gets as an input an array of strings, and creates a two-dimensoinal array of type char, the number of lines is as the number of words in the string and in each line there is a reversed array of the letters in the word.

for example if my input is: start at the end!

my output will be :

[t, r, a, t, s]

[t, a]

[e, h, t]

[!, d, n, e]

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char thelist[][] = new char[args.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        thelist[i] = new char[args[i].length()];

        for (int k = 0; k < args[i].length(); k++) {
            char letter = args[i].charAt(args[i].length() - k - 1);
            thelist[i][k] = letter;
        }

        for (char[] word : thelist) {
            String list = Arrays.toString(word);
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: what output do you get ?!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this :

```
   String str ="start at the end!";
   String[] splitString = str.split(" ");
   int length=0;
   for(String string:splitString ){
       if(string.length()>length){
           length=string.length();
       }
   }
   Character[][] charArray = new Character[splitString.length][length];
   int index=0;
   for(String string:splitString ){
       length=string.length();
       for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
           charArray[index][--length]=string.charAt(i);
       }
       index++;
   }

   for (int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
       for (int j=0;j<charArray[i].length && charArray[i][j]!=null;j++) {
           System.out.print(charArray[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

OUTPUT:

```
trats
ta
eht
!dne
```

Answer (score 0):

While editing your question I fixed indentation of your code which showed your problem clearly: you placed code responsible for printing result array in same loop which fills this array. In other words you are printing array after you add new row to it.

That is why you see results in form

```
[row1]
null
null
null
[row1]
[row2]
null
null
[row1]
[row2]
[row3]
null
[row1]
[row2]
[row3]
[row4]
```

To solve this problem simply place loop responsible for printing outside of loop responsible in generating content of result array (remember that indentation is not responsible for scoping but placement of `{` and `}` brackets is, so move one `}` from end before printing loop). So change your code to

```
char thelist[][] = new char[args.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    thelist[i] = new char[args[i].length()];

    for (int k = 0; k < args[i].length(); k++) {
        char letter = args[i].charAt(args[i].length() - k - 1);
        thelist[i][k] = letter;
    }
}

for (char[] word : thelist) {
    String list = Arrays.toString(word);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting extra lines because you are printing inside the outer for loops. try this. it should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char thelist[][] = new char[args.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        thelist[i] = new char[args[i].length()];

        for (int k = 0; k < args[i].length(); k++) {
            char letter = args[i].charAt(args[i].length() - k - 1);
            thelist[i][k] = letter;
        }
    }

    for (char[] word : thelist) {
            String list = Arrays.toString(word);
            System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippets are for code examples which can be run by browser (HTML/JavaScript/CSS). Java code should be placed in Code Sample (represented in editor by `{}`).